# Converting String to Date in View

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, view, data-conversion

I have a problem here, at first I have to `convert` the date (that is a string) in my view into the Date, but I don't know how to do that.

Here is my sample:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[DataFoodView]
AS
SELECT * FROM
( VALUES (1, N'mik', 5, '2020-5-2'),
         (1, N'coca', 5, '2020-5-2'))
AS SM (FID, Fname, Fcount, FDate);
```

But because of this creating I can't change the format of the date.

PS: I have to use this kind of view in my code.

Comment: Please tag your question with database that you are using.

Comment: I added the "sql-server" tag based on the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using strings for dates, and you sort of alluded to this yourself in your question.  Since you are using SQL Server, you could use `TRY_CONVERT` on your text dates:

```sql
SELECT FID, Fname, Fcount, TRY_CONVERT(datetime, FDate) AS FDate
FROM [dbo].[DataFoodView];
```

But the best fix would be to just use valid date literals in your view definition:

```sql
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[DataFoodView]
AS
SELECT * FROM
( VALUES (1, N'mik', 5, '20200502'),
         (1, N'coca', 5, '20200502'))
AS SM (FID, Fname, Fcount, FDate);
```

Now the date literals are unambiguous and mean what you intend.

Comment: I dont wanna use string neither in Date but I dont know how to use it in the correct format! btw thank u for answering, u saved my day:)

Answer (score 0):

Try use convert function

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[DataFoodView]
AS
SELECT * FROM
( VALUES (1, N'mik', 5, convert(datetime, '2020-5-2',120)),
         (1, N'coca', 5, convert(datetime, '2020-5-2',120)))
AS SM (FID, Fname, Fcount, FDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server is very flexible about recognizing date formats.  So you can convert in the `SELECT`:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[DataFoodView] AS
    SELECT FID, Fname, Fcount, CONVERT(DATE, FDate) as FDate
    FROM ( VALUES (1, N'mik', 5, '2020-5-2'),
                  (1, N'coca', 5, '2020-5-2')
         ) AS SM(FID, Fname, Fcount, FDate);
```

Or, you can convert the first value in the `VALUES()` (or all of them, if you prefer):

```
CREATE VIEW DataFoodView AS
    SELECT FID, Fname, Fcount, FDate
    FROM ( VALUES (1, N'mik', 5, CONVERT(DATE, '2020-5-2')),
                  (1, N'coca', 5, '2020-5-2')
         ) AS SM(FID, Fname, Fcount, FDate);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=548636c40fe8ef89462bbb50401f5169) is a db<>fiddle.